# How to list FTP server directories using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We have ftp server with few directories and files under it, I am able to connect through browser and access directories successfully. However when used the same server:port with credentials not able to connect. Tried using JSR233 sampler also to list the files, but no success.

please guide.

TestPlan:
FTP request defaults (Server IP and port:21)>get(RETR)
--Thread Group
---FTP request (nothing added as remote file since just want to get list of files/directories)
---JSR233 sampler with below script

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
ftpClient.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", 21)
ftpClient.login("'abc", "tesst")

ftpClient.listFiles().each {
log.info(it.getName())
}

log.info("---")
```

for FTP request getting an error as below:
    Response message: java.io.FileNotFoundException:   (The system cannot find the path specified)
Request is going as:
    ftp://xx.xx.xx.xx:21/ (Ascii)  ->
for JSR233 sampler: shows success without any response, files are list listed even in jmeter log also.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Added screen shot of jmeter.log and .jmx file.

[image: jmeter.log info]

[![FTP req defaults[![FTP req[![JSR233 sampler[![res msg: The system cannot find the path specified)
[[image: JSR233 results]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHj5u.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd7mJ.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSKGg.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUaIy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFDVZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Able to get results in the Jmeter log file now, there was extra ' in the credentials going.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call [FTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#changeWorkingDirectory(java.lang.String)) method before listing files as your `abc` user.

Prior to doing anything else you might want to test whether you connected to the FTP server or not by calling [ftpClient.isConnected()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/SocketClient.html#isConnected()) method

Also be aware that [`FTPClient.login()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#login(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method returns `true` if login is successful and `false` otherwise.

According to the [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) article your code needs to be amended like:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
ftpClient.connect('xx.xx.xx.xx', 21)
if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
    if (ftpClient.login('abc', 'tesst')) {
        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory('/path/to/the/folder/with/files/') // navigate to the folder which content you want to list

        ftpClient.listFiles().each {
            log.info(it.getName())
        }
    } else {
        log.error('Failed to login')
    }
} else {
    log.error('Failed to connect')
}
```

If none of the above hints will help post update your question with the  *jmeter.log* file contents.

Comment: Thanks @DmitriT. I have added all the information related to jmeter.log and results to the query. Able to get directories listed in jmeter.log, but not able to figure it out to use these values (how to extract these file/directory names and use it furthur - Jmeter variables)